# node.js request get redirect chain

Tags: node.js, redirect, request, http-redirect

Is it possible to use the `request` module to look at the entire redirect chain, like how `puppeteer` does it?

I'd like to be able to see each of the status codes / urls / how many redirects happen when I go a site

for example, if i request 'http://apple.com'
the url is set up to redirect to

`https://www.apple.com` (in this case, the chain is 1)
I'd like to know that (1) that redirect happened and (2) how many redirects it took to get to that

If this isn't possible with `request`, are there any other libraries? (I'm not using `puppeteer` anymore because `puppeteer` doesn't work well with testing attachments)

Comment: `got` has got `redirect` event in stream mode, https://github.com/sindresorhus/got#gotstreamurl-options . I'm not that sure about `request`. The mention of Puppeteer seems misleading, it's not HTTP request lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is it possible, it can be even easier to use:

Redirect Object: https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/lib/redirect.js

```
request.get (
      {
        uri: `http://somesite.com/somepage`,
        followAllRedirects: true
      },
      (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) {
          // there's an error
        }
        if (!res) {
          // there isn't a response
        }

        if (res) {
            const status = res.statusCode; // 404 , 200, 301, etc
            const chain = res.request._redirect.redirects; // each redirect has some info too, see the redirect link above
            const contentType = res.headers["content-type"] // yep, you can do this too
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out, yes, it is completely possible.

```
const request = require('request')

request.get({
    uri: 'http://apple.com',
    followAllRedirects: true
}, function (err, res, body) {
    console.log(res.request._redirect.redirectsFollowed)
    console.log(res.request._redirect.redirects) // this gives the full chain of redirects


});
```